# horizontal ScrollPanel in mgwt

Tags: java, gwt, mgwt

I need a horizontal ScrollPanel in mgwt and tried to use:

```
  contactHorizontalScrollPanel = new ScrollPanel();
  contactHorizontalScrollPanel.setShowScrollBarX(true);
  contactHorizontalScrollPanel.setScrollingEnabledX(true);
```

but I always get a vertical ScrollBar for my panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may help. Use standard GWT panel:

```
contactHorizontalScrollPanel = new ScrollPanel();

HorizontalPanel hPanel = new HorizontalPanel();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     Button btn = new Button("" + i);
     hPanel.add(btn);
}

contactHorizontalScrollPane.setWidget(hPanel);
```

Comment: putting the horizontal panel into the scroll panel worked for me. thanks!